# Webkit dependencies

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, webkit

I've download the files in the http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/files/ and I made a browser application.
On my pc windows 10 with VS2012 is working fine. But on my other pc with Win 7 again with vs 2012 is working but the webkit browser is not showing anything. There's no error but nothing it shows in the webkit browser.
I made a setup, I've included all the dll files from the webkit and I've installed in several pc's.
Same thing happen again. The program works fine without errors but the browser is blank.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it. The link I tried to open was http://http://www.something
That's why nothing happened but the strange thing is that I didn't see anything like an error page not found or something else